# Safe navigation operator in angular .ts file

Tags: angular, performance, angular-components, safe-navigation-operator

Can we use safe navigation operator in .ts file angular application? 
 Does it cause any performance related issues if we include in .ts file?

Comment: It's built into the syntax of TypeScript, why shouldn't you be able to use it in a ts file? Have you tried if it works?

Comment: I've tried and till now it is working fine. But my doubt is, whether it causes any issues if we use in ts file, so that I thought to clarify it, once before using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Optional Chaining operator is part of TypeScript since [TypeScript version 3.7](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html) from November 2019 (three years ago). So as long as your TypeScript compiler runs 3.7 or newer, there should be no problem at all using this operator.

Comment: Yes, it wont cause any issues with the typescript version 3.7 and above, so we can use safe navigation operator or optional chaining in ts and html files of angular application.